# Questions about real sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

If $\{x_n\}$ is a real sequence and say only finitely many terms are rational, can we conclude that there is a a natural number $N$ so that for all $n>N$, $x_n$ is irrational? and similarly if there are only a finite number of irrationals in our sequence, there is a $K$ so that $x_n$ is rational for all $n>K$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P$ be any property that a term of your sequence may have or not. Then:

> If only finitely many terms have property $P$ then there is a natural number $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $x_n$ does not have porperty $P$.

Indeed, by assumption the set $A:=\{\,n\in\mathbb N\mid x_n\text{ has property } P\,\}$ is finite so that we can let $N=\max A$ (or $N=1$ if $A$ is empty).

Comment: Thank you, I was doubting this for some reason...